# What is the Hamiltonian of an electron moving through a conductor?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-electrodynamics, hamiltonian, conductors

I am specifically asking for the formula for an electron moving through a wire. I would also like to know where it comes from/how it is derived. I was not able to find any answers for the potential energy or Hamiltonian of this situation. To give a little more context, I need this to solve for the wavefunction of a singular electron. Because of that, I need to be able to have the Hamiltonian of the said electron.

Comment: I don't think there are enough details to answer the question as asked. What specifically are you trying to model? Is the electron interacting with the lattice of the conductor or with other electrons?

Comment: I apologize for not including enough. Honestly for now I just want the sum of the kinetic and potential energy of the electron. The schrodinger equation thing is not too big a deal. The kinetic energy is easy to find, assuming no other forces are in play. But the potential energy is much harder. I should add that I am assuming there is no gravity or other external force.